# How to keep Kendo Window open after POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, popup, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-window

**Setup**
In MVC app I have 2 views. The Main view which is referencing to _Layout view Has a Button "Show".  Then I have another shared view which has a kendo Upload control.  Upload view is NOT referencing _Layout view but it's in shared folder so I can reuse it.

**Requirement**
When user clicks on the Show button on Main view, I want to show Upload view in popup window. On popup window if user does not select a file, then I want to show error message on the same popup window.

**Issues**
When user click's on upload button without selecting file, the model gets posted to server to Upload method as expected. Inside the method if

> ModelState.IsValid == false

, im returning to same Upload view. But then I get error

> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined.

now I can keep pressing continue on IE error window, and I finally I get upload view and I could see the error in ValidationSummary, however it’s not showing as popup instead it renders as a plain html page

Below is my Code

**Main View**

```html
@model MainModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var uploadwindow = $("#uploadwindow");

        $("#btnShow").click(function (e) {
            uploadwindow.data("kendoWindow")
                .open()
                .center();
        });

    });
</script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnShow">Show</button>

@(Html.Kendo().Window()
.Name("uploadwindow")
.Title("Select the files to upload")
.Width(600)
.Modal(true)
.Visible(false)
.LoadContentFrom("Upload", "Main")
)
```

**Upload View**

```html
@model UploadModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Main", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @(Html.Kendo().Upload().Name("files"))
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
}
```

```html
public class MainController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            MainModel model = new MainModel()
            return View(model);
        }

        public ActionResult Upload()
        {
            UploadModel model = new UploadModel();
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload (UploadModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
            {
               //I want stay on the same Upload view to show error messages
   //Here I get JQuery exception when model is not valid
                return View(model); 
            }
            else
            {
         // Do something here and Close the POPUP Window
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
    public class UploadModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please click the browse button and select a file.")]    
        public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }     
    }
```